# Where is the SQL Query Analyzer in SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, ssms-2012

I have some SQL thats getting run and it is taking to long to return the results / parse / display, etc. application.

I have SQL Server Management Studio 2012 installed.but i am not able to find SQL Query Analyser.
Any Input will be appreciable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Take a look at this link http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/07/10/query-analyzer-or-management-studio.aspx

The Query Analyzer (QA) was the query tool provided with SQL Server up until SQL Server 2000. In SQL Server 2005 and above it was superseded by SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). If you would like to detect any performance problems in some of your queries you can use the execution plan to determine what is the culprit.

- How to analyze a query : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191227(v=sql.105).aspx
- Briefing of how to analyze an execution plan : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Are 2 links which definately can get you going. Also take a look at this introduction to SSMS 2012 which also can be useful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YipAwZ3Riok

Comment: The first link seems to be broken. Is there another location for this article @Mez ?

Comment: The first link is offline, but Wayback Web has a copy here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150101073222/http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2008/07/10/query-analyzer-or-management-studio.aspx

Answer (score 6):

starting from SQL Server 2005, SQL Server Management Studio is the new management tool (Enterprise manager replaced). Thus, the "New Query" tab is the place where you can write down and analyze your queries. You can see the Execution Plan, client data and so on.

SQL Query Analyzer does not exist anymore.