# Is there anyway where I can get the data hit in SQL server?

Tags: sql, neo4j, cypher

I am working on neo4j and SQL server. I come across `PROFILE` key word in neo4j where you can see the execution plan based on DB data hit. I am trying to find the equivalent in SQL server but so far I could not find it. I fount **Include actual execution plan** in SQL server where I can see the cost for a given query. Does anyone know how can I get the data hit in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

In the distant past I used Microsoft Query Analyzer (QA) to perform the kind of query performance analysis. The QA came included with SQL Server up until Microsoft SQL Server 2000.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/24820408 starting from 2005 you need to install Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to get an equivalent tool:

> The Query Analyzer (QA) was the query tool provided with SQL Server up until SQL Server 2000. In SQL Server 2005 and above it was superseded by SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS). If you would like to detect any performance problems in some of your queries you can use the execution plan to determine what is the culprit.
>
> How to analyze a query : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191227(v=sql.105).aspx
> Briefing of how to analyze an execution plan : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

The current release of SSMS is free to download, install and use.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms to install a suitable version.